# Add Item to Object Explorer Context Menu in SSMS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssms, vspackage

I am writing a VSPackage Extention for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2016.
I am currently facing the challenge to add an item or a submenu in the "right-click" context menu when clicking on a SQL Server Instance.

I want to add a submenu of commands where the red rectangle is (i.e. at the end of the context menu).

I did a bit of reading and I should be able to do it .vsct file. Unfortunately I cannot find any overview of **SSMS** Guids for Menus/Groups and so on.

There is one for Visual Studio but not for SQL Server Mangement Studio which has a set of different menus that VS doesn't has.

Link for Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc826118.aspx

I appreciate any Input for this topic because there seems to be not too much Information out there for VSPackage Extention and SSMS. More about deprecated Add-In's.

[image: Context Menu in SSMS]

Comment: I do it like this (in all it's ugliness!) https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/tree/master/src/GUI/SSMSToolbox/SSMSEngine and https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/SSMSToolbox/Package/SqlCeToolboxPackage.cs#L226

Comment: @ErikEJ You should post it as an answer. I copied large parts of your code.

Comment: @ErikEJ, sorry,  I did not find in your code how to add my menu (command) to the SSMS Object Explorer. I see ho you add to your tree but not to SQL Server Object tree.

Comment: @ErikEJ Is for SSMS18 also impossible to use vsct for Object explorer? And for now it is possible only by code to add menu items?